# unity ads not working on playstore but works on test?

Tags: unity-game-engine, logging, ads, unityads

Hi I just put my game on the playstore and it works now (finally) the only problem is that the ads aren't working but they worked on unity editor when testing it. This is what the log shows:

Please consider upgrading to the Packman Distribution of the Unity Ads SDK.  The Asset Store distribution will not longer be supported after Unity 2018.3
UnityEngine.Advertisements.Advertisement:Initialize(String, Boolean)
monetization:Start() (at Assets/monetization.cs:17)

I am not really sure that this means, could someone help out?

Answer (score 0):

That means you need to update the ads package manager.

what i did was i removed the unity monetization assets i got from the asset store and i update my unity ads package and the ads began to work